# bash regexp to extract part of URL

Tags: regex, bash, sed

From the following  URL:

`https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/]`

I need to extract the following part:

`test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/`

I'm pretty bad at regex. I came up with the following but it doesn't work:

```
sed -n "s/^.*browser\(test-lab.*/.*/\).*$/\1/p"
```

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try with awk solution also and let me know if this helps you.

```
echo "https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/" | awk '{sub(/.*browser\//,"");sub(/\/$/,"");print}'
```

**Explanation:** Simply, substituting everything till `browser/` then substituting last `/` with NULL.

**EDIT1:** Adding a sed solution here too.

```
sed 's/\(.[^//]*\)\/\/\(.[^/]*\)\(.[^/]*\)\(.[^/]*\)\/\(.*\)/\5/'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/
```

**Explanation of sed command:** Dividing the whole line into parts and using sed's ability to keep the matched regex into memory so here are the dividers I used.

***(.[^//]*):*** Which will have the value till https: in it and if anyone wants to print it you could use `\1` for it because this is very first buffer for sed.

***//:*** Now as per URL  `//` comes to mentioning them now.

***(.[^/]*):*** Now comes the 2nd part for sed's buffer which will have value `console.developers.google.com` in it, because REGEX looks for very first occurrence of `/` and stops matching there itself.

***(.[^/]*)  && (.[^/]*) && /(.*):*** These next 3 occurrences works on same method of storing buffers like they will look for first occurrence of `/` and keep the value from last matched letter's next occurrence to till 1st `/` comes.

***/\5/:*** Now I am substituting everything with `\5` means 5th buffer which contains values as per OP's instructions.

Comment: Thanks this helps

Comment: @AnkitGupta, glad that it helped you, I added explanation also. Let me know if you have any queries on same. Keep learning and keep sharing knowledge, have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different sed delimiter and don't forget to escape the braces.

```
avinash:~/Desktop$ echo 'https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/]' | sed 's~.*/browser/\([^/]*/[^/]*/\).*~\1~'
test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/
```

OR

Use grep with `oP` parameters.

```
avinash:~/Desktop$ echo 'https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/]' | grep -oP  '/browser/\K[^/]*/[^/]*/'
test-lab-acteghe53j0sf-jrf3f8u8p12n4/2017-09-27_15:23:07.566833_MPoy/
```